# Function Pointer to Class Member Function Error

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I'm creating a system that has 7 categories of data (thus, 7 different objects) that users can add, edit and delete from. To be more efficient, I made a utility class extending from  that defines add, edit and delete functions more specific to the program. Because the user can input data in the Add function, I'm passing a class member function pointer into List's addObject class that inputs the data specific for that object. Thus, the List class adds the object and each class has a class member function for their specific variables.

I have this error in the addObject class:

> Called object type 'bool (Product::*)()' is not a function or function pointer

it seems like the List class can't access the Product data. When I added #include "Product.h" in the head, the compiler sent many errors about double initialization of Product functions, which is very odd because ALL classes have #ifndef, #define and #endif at top and bottom respectfully.

Here's my code - I added what I think is important for understanding, so let me know if you need more to understand:

Main:

```
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Product.h"
#include "List.h"
int main () 
{
    bool (Product::*prodFunc) () = &Product::addProduct;
    allProducts.addObject(allProducts.back(), prodFunc); 
}
```

in the List Class:

```
template<class DT>
bool List<DT>::addObject(DT & previous, bool (DT::* func)())
{
    bool success = true;
    int newID = 1 + (previous.getID());
    cout << "New ID: " << newID << endl;
    previous.setID(newID);
    func(); //Error here
    return success;
}
```

Product's addProduct class:

```
bool Product::addProduct()
{
    bool success = true;
    cout << "Please enter the following for your new product:\n";
    addItem();
    return success;
}
```

I'm sure (or at least hope) it's something real simple that I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: `func(); //Error here` -- Hint -- When you call a member function by pointer, you need an object specified somewhere in the call.  Where is the object in that call?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to call the member function on the `previous` parameter, the way you make such a call is like this:

```
(previous.*func)();
```

Or, because the syntax looks gnarly, most advise using `std::invoke` instead

```
std::invoke(func, previous);
```

Which will automatically deduce that `func` is a member function and should be called with `previous`

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass a pointer to a non-static member function as a bare function; it must be called on some object of the class's type. The easy way to implement this is with [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

```
auto prodFunc = std::bind(&Product::addProduct, &allProducts.back());
allProducts.addObject(allProducts.back(), &prodFunc);
```

Alternatively, you could declare `Product::addProduct()` as a `static` member function, in which case your code should function as intended. Looking at how you are using it, that may be what you actually want.